# Xslt 2 convert non-unique elements to attributes for grid

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file with this structure

```html
<levels>
  <level id="0" qd="NE">
    <gate>99</gate>
    <zone>2</zone>
    <laydown>4</laydown>
  </level>
  <level id="0" qd="SE">
    <gate>1</gate>
    <zone>6</zone>
    <laydown>1</laydown>
    <laydown>2</laydown>
    <laydown>3</laydown>
    <zone>5</zone>
    <zone>5</zone>
  </level>
</levels>
```

And I need to convert it to something like this to display in a grid

```html
<level id="0" qd="NE" gate="99" zone="2"  laydown="3">
<level id="0" qd="NE" gate="1" zone="5,6" laydown="1,2,3">
```

I have found xslt that works but not where the elements are non-unique. They only pick up the LAST element suggesting that each element is overwriting the previous. Have not included it as I would rather see the proper solution than my bodged attempt just made to work. I am an xsl/xslt newbie so any annotation will be helpful.  I work with vs 2013

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you want to convert the elements? Does each `level` element in the input result in a `level` element in the output? Why does the first `level` in your result sample say `laydown="3"` and not `laydown="4"`?

Comment: Each level element will result in a level element in the output.

Comment: Sorry I created the output by hand and it should say laydown 4. And the second qd should be SE. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating an attribute for each element, it will definitely overwrite any previous attribute that you've created (with the same name).

You tagged this as XSLT 2.0, so here's a 2.0 option. The output doesn't match yours exactly; your example doesn't make a whole lot of sense in a couple of places. (Like why does the first `level` have `laydown="3"` instead of `laydown="4"` and both `level`'s have `qd="NE"`.)

**XML Input**

```
<levels>
    <level id="0" qd="NE">
        <gate>99</gate>
        <zone>2</zone>
        <laydown>4</laydown>
    </level>
    <level id="0" qd="SE">
        <gate>1</gate>
        <zone>6</zone>
        <laydown>1</laydown>
        <laydown>2</laydown>
        <laydown>3</laydown>
        <zone>5</zone>
        <zone>5</zone>
    </level>
</levels>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:local="local" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="local:sort">
        <xsl:param name="seq"/>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$seq">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="level">
        <xsl:variable name="level" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(*/name())">
                <xsl:attribute name="{.}" 
                    select="string-join(distinct-values(local:sort($level/*[name()=current()])),',')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<levels>
   <level id="0" qd="NE" gate="99" zone="2" laydown="4"/>
   <level id="0" qd="SE" gate="1" zone="5,6" laydown="1,2,3"/>
</levels>
```

Comment: I am getting an error in vs2013 underlining xsl:function saying The element 'stylesheet' in namespace ... has invalid child element 'function'.  And when I run the XLST debugger I get an error Expected token ')', found '('.  on this line <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(*/name())">

Comment: @NickHoare, you asked for XSLT 2.0 so you will need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 from Saxonica. Microsoft/VS does only support XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Sorry @NickHoare I didn't notice the vs 2013 in the question (I stopped reading at "I'm an xslt newbie".) Like Martin stated, you'll need a 2.0 processor to use this answer.

Comment: So do I need an XSLT 1.0 solution? I flagged my first attempts as Version 2 and had no errors. I tried your code and I am using it in an XMLDatasource. Debugging shows no errors, however the grid bound to this only shows the first values with a comma where there ought to be more than one. Does version 1 processing just cope with version 2 code without actually failing?

Comment: @NickHoare Asking another question is the right thing to do. But for your information: an XSLT 1.0 processor can process a stylesheet where `version="2.0"` is specified. Most constructs in 2.0 are already available in 1.0. But the answer above uses XPath functions that are exclusive to 2.0 (e.g. `distinct-values()`). So, in this case the processor cannot "cope without failing".